# CSS3 increase space between circle and text

Tags: jquery, html, css

**CSS3 increase space bwteen circle and text**

I've this code for padding it does not make any difference, even I removed a padding still nothing:

```
   ul.lists_index { line-height:10px; padding:0 0 -10px 0;}
   ul.lists_index li{ line-height:20px;}
```

Is it possible to have code to increase space bwteen top of blue circles and bottom of text?

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/circle_space.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/circle_space.png)

Comment: Can you create an working example in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @ sandeep: I wish I know how to use jsfiddle if I did and I wouldn't be asking here. My sincere apologies, that I could be more help to you? At least I've in included a HTML file.

Comment: JSFiddle is a very simple tool; separate your JavaScript, CSS, and HTML, and the whole thing gets parsed immediately in the same window. I can't see why you'd be unable to use that.

Comment: Point taken, unless I know the solution to a problem e.g. JS and CSS fix then I can use jsfiddle. In the meantime, I can use js fiddle if I know the solution of the code? in this case, I didn't e.g.  li:nth-child(2n){}. I didn't know earlier...now, I know the workaround.

Comment: `padding: 0 0 -10px 0` You can't have negative padding; you're probably confusing that with `margin`.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I appreciate it so negative padding do not work? Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your CSS -

```
#content_index_right ul li:nth-child(odd){ padding: 10px 0;}
```

If you need support in Old IE browsers then use jquery and add-

```
$('#content_index_right ul li:odd').css('padding', '10px 0');
```

Comment: Thank you. What about #content_index_left?

Comment: +1 you can write like this also li:nth-child(2n){}. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/7uhsm/1/

Comment: #content_index_left ul li:nth-child(odd){ padding: 10px 0;}